# java how to receive web service response in JSON

Tags: java, json, web-services

i am new to web services i am calling a web service that should returns JSON with the folliwng code - the problem is i am getting the response in xml format 
when i am trying the same parameters using google rest api - the response is in jSON
any ideas what i am doing wrong ?

```
 public static  String getSFData(String urlSuffix) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException , IOException    
 {


    String header = "Basic XXXXX";
    URL url = new URL("https://api2.successfactors.eu/odata/v2/"+urlSuffix);
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("authorization",header);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null )
    {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
    }
    String response = stringBuffer.toString();
    System.out.println("response"+response);
    return response;

 }
```

Comment: [`Content-Type`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) specifies the type of content you're *sending*, and you don't send any content (as you well shouldn't with a `GET`). To specify the desired *response* content type, set the [`Accept`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header value instead.

Comment: can you show me how - i don't understand

Comment: As I said, set the `Accept` header value *instead*, i.e. replace `"Content-Type"` with `"Accept"`.

Comment: got it !!i added connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); solved my problem - thanks Andreas!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You could try the API URL like `http://api2.successfactors.eu/odata/v2/User?
$format=json` to get data in JSON.

Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Try the following after set content type.

```
    connection.connect();

    int status = connection.getResponseCode();

    switch (status) {
        case 200:
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            String response = stringBuilder.toString();
            System.out.println("response : " + response);
    }
```

Comment: thanks - but this is not helping - the response is in xml and i need it to be in json

Comment: So, may be you have to Map the XML to JAVA object, then you can convert it in json.

Comment: @RahavMagen in a documentation i have found that `$format=json` in API URL could get the data in JSON format. You try this. See my updated answer

Comment: yep you are right - it is also olving it - i added ?$format=json and it helped  but i actualy used what andrea suggested connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");  also solved my probelm - thanks for your help ( i don't have enought reputation to update the score )